# Descartes number

Tags: number-theory, math-history, perfect-numbers

In 1638 Descartes wrote a letter to Mersenne where he talks about how the number $$D=3^2⋅7^2⋅11^2⋅13^2⋅22021$$ would be an odd perfect number if we mistakingly assume that $22021$ is prime. My question is, do we know what method Descartes used when he found his number and does anyone know where I can find a copy of the letter that he sent to Mersenne in November of 1638?

I've tried several searches online, and at our local academic library, but have had no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $D = 32\cdot72\cdot112\cdot132\cdot22021= 750 \, 086 \, 701 \, 056$ ;$D_{\text{Peter}} = 198\,585\,576\,189$

Comment: $D_{Peter}$, nice idea :)

Comment: In fact, "$D_{Peter}$" WOULD be a perfect odd number, if $22021$ WERE prime.

Comment: You might try posting to [History of Math and Science](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I found this. Helpful? http://faculty.missouri.edu/~bankswd/papers/2008_Descartes_Final.pdf

Comment: Descartes à Mersenne, 15 novembre 1638 (lettre CXLIX), into [Œuvres, éd. Adam et Tannery, Tome II](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Descartes_-_%C5%92uvres,_%C3%A9d._Adam_et_Tannery,_II.djvu/463), page 429.

Comment: This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124167) is related and the answer contained therein attempts to respond to your first inquiry.

Comment: Thank you Mauro, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I think you should post your comment as an answer to this question, since it actually answers the OP's inquiry, so that the question does not remain unanswered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The letter is :

- Descartes à Mersenne, 15 novembre 1638 (lettre CXLIX).

We can find it into : [Œuvres, éd. Adam et Tannery, Tome II](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Descartes_-_%C5%92uvres,_%C3%A9d._Adam_et_Tannery,_II.djvu/463), page 429.