# Did Descartes and Frénicle consider deficient-perfect numbers?

Tags: number-theory, math-history, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

[Holdener and Rachfal](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.2019.1584515?journalCode=uamm20) show that, if $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ (satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$), then $q^{(k-1)/2} n^2$ is [deficient-perfect](http://oeis.org/A271816).

[Descartes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124167), in the year 1638, knew that $22021 \cdot \left(3^2 \cdot 7^2 \cdot {11^2} \cdot {13^2}\right)$ would have been an odd perfect number if $22021$ were prime.  (Notice that $3^2 \cdot 7^2 \cdot {11^2} \cdot {13^2}$ is the lone odd deficient-perfect number that we know of to this day.)

Here is my question:

> Did Descartes and/or Frénicle consider deficient-perfect numbers in their attempts to solve the problem of existence of odd perfect numbers?

I dare to conjecture that the answer is *YES*, but I am not a math historian and I currently do not know which (authoritative) sources to check.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, just remarks with myself ideas about even perfect numbers, that I think similar than the statement of previous authors. I am an amateur mathematician.

My belief is that the following conjeture holds (thus that it is very difficult to find a counterexample). I don't know if this conjecture is in the literature.

> **Conjecture.** *An integer* $n\geq 1$ *is an even perfect number if an only if* $$\operatorname{rad}(n)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}-2\frac{\varphi(n)}{\sigma(n)}}.\tag{1}$$

Here $\sigma(m)$ is the sum of divisors function, $\varphi(m)$ the Euler's totient function and $\operatorname{rad}(m)$ the radical of the integer $m\geq 1$ (see the Wikipedia [*Radical of an integer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer)).

Thus with this *answer* you can make a comparison with the statement you cite from the authors, because it is easy/obvious to prove, by cases, that any even perfect number satisfies $(1)$. Thus it is obvious that if $n$ is an even perfect number then $$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}-2\frac{\varphi(n)}{\sigma(n)}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}}\tag{2}$$ is integer, and it is the integer $\operatorname{rad}(n)$. We see that $(2)$ can be written as $\frac{n}{\frac{1}{2}n-\varphi(n)},$ thus we've next easy/obvious fact.

> **Fact.** If $n$ is an even perfect number then $$\frac{n}{\frac{1}{2}n-\varphi(n)}$$ is an integer.

That is the fact that I wanted to evoke if you want to make comparisons to yourself problem. I hope that you get an answer for your nice question. Good luck.

---

I tried to relate even perfect numbers to the Euler's totient, my guess is that even perfect numbers maybe are closely-related to the Euler's totient function, in fact here we've the following conjecture.

> **Conjecture.** *An integer* $m\geq 1$ *satisfies* $$2\varphi(\varphi((m+1)(2m+1)))=(m+1)\varphi(m)\tag{3}$$
>   *if and only if* $(m+1)(2m+1)$ *is an even perfect number.*

Again I know how to prove $\Rightarrow$, but I can not to get the full proof or find a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, I hope help with my answer, if you don't know it.

Comment: Taking off from @user686930's answer, I want to check the following conjecture:  If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number, then
$$\frac{2N}{N - 2\varphi(N)}$$
is an integer.

**Attempt at proof:**

Note that
$$\frac{2N}{N - 2\varphi(N)} = \frac{\sigma(N)}{N - 2\varphi(N)} = \frac{\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)}{q^k n^2 - 2\varphi(q^k)\varphi(n^2)} = \frac{\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)}{q^k n^2 - 2\varphi(q^k)\bigg(n\varphi(n)\bigg)}.$$
In particular, the numerator is even and the denominator is odd.  Hence, the quotient is not an integer.  **QED**

Comment: If I remember well (I take notes in my notebook but these are sparse) if it easy to prove that odd perfect numbers don't satisfy $(1)$ (dividing by $2$). On the other hand  there is a **typo** in the last paragraph concerning the conjecture related to the equation $(3)$ since if I remember well I know how to prove $\Leftarrow$, and not $\Rightarrow$, thus I know how to prove that if $(m+1)\cdot(2m+1)$ is an even perfect number then the integer $m$ satisfies $$2\varphi(\varphi((m+1)\cdot(2m+1)))=(m+1)\varphi(m).$$ 
I add thus this comment to clarify my words and mistake @JoseArnaldoBebita-Dris

Comment: Kindly take a look at this other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3284645), @user686930.