# Is it possible to improve on the bounds for $\varphi(N)/N$, if $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, totient-function, upper-lower-bounds, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form.  That is, $q$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

From a comment underneath this [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3284420), we have the equation (and corresponding inequalities)
$$1 < \frac{\varphi(n)}{n}\cdot\frac{N}{\varphi(N)} = \frac{q}{q-1} \leq \frac{5}{4}$$
since $q$ is prime with $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ implies that $q \geq 5$.
This implies that
$$\frac{4}{5} \leq \dfrac{\dfrac{\varphi(N)}{N}}{\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n}} = \frac{q-1}{q} < 1.$$

But from the following source:
[Advanced Problem H-661, On Odd Perfect Numbers, Proposed by J. L´opez Gonz´alez, Madrid, Spain and F. Luca, Mexico (Vol. 45, No. 4, November 2007), Fibonacci Quarterly](https://www.fq.math.ca/Problems/Advanced_Problems_NOV2009.pdf), we have the bounds
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} < \frac{1}{2}.$$

However, we also have
$$\frac{\varphi(N)}{N} = \frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k}\cdot\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}.$$
Notice that
$$\frac{4}{5} \leq \frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k} = \frac{q^k \bigg(1 - \frac{1}{q}\bigg)}{q^k} = \frac{q - 1}{q} < 1.$$ 
Therefore, we have the bounds
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} = \frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k}\cdot\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{\varphi(n)}{n},$$
and
$$\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} \leq \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} = \frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k}\cdot\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{1}{2},$$
which implies that
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{5}{8}.$$

WolframAlpha gives the rational approximation
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} \approx 0.4600409433626.$$

Here is my question:

> Is it possible to improve on the bounds for $\varphi(N)/N$, if $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?

**MOTIVATION FOR THE INQUIRY**

It can be shown that the equation
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}\cdot\frac{N}{\varphi(N)} = \frac{q}{q-1}$$
together with the bounds
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} < \frac{1}{2}$$
and
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{5}{8}$$
imply
$$0.92 \approx \dfrac{\dfrac{120}{217\zeta(3)}}{\dfrac{1}{2}} < \frac{q}{q-1} < \dfrac{\dfrac{5}{8}}{\dfrac{120}{217\zeta(3)}} \approx 1.358574729,$$
from which we obtain trivial bounds.

Nonetheless, it can be shown that the equation
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}\cdot\frac{N}{\varphi(N)} = \frac{q}{q-1}$$
together with the upper bound $\varphi(N)/N < 1/2$ implies that
$$q < \frac{x}{x-1}$$
where
$$x = \frac{2\varphi(n)}{n}.$$
Thus, if we can improve the upper bound for $\varphi(N)/N$ to something smaller than $1/2$ (say $1/2 - \varepsilon$ for some **tiny** $\varepsilon > 0$), then we can improve the coefficient of $\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}$ in $x$ to some number bigger than $2$.  Likewise, if we can get a better lower bound for $\varphi(N)/N$, then we will be able to get an improved lower bound for $\varphi(n)/n$.  Together, they would translate (hopefully!) to a numerical upper bound for the special/Euler prime $q$!

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!!!

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special/Euler prime $q$.

From the equation and lower bound for $\varphi(N)/N$
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} = \frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k}\cdot\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}$$
and the equation
$$\frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k} = \frac{q - 1}{q},$$
we get the lower bound
$$2\cdot\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)}\cdot\frac{q}{q - 1} < \frac{2\varphi(n)}{n} = x.$$
This implies that we have the upper bound
$$q < \frac{x}{x-1} < \frac{2\cdot\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)}\cdot\frac{q}{q - 1}}{\bigg(2\cdot\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)}\cdot\frac{q}{q - 1}\bigg) - 1}$$
which can be solved using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20q%20%3C%20(2(120%2F(217(zeta(3))))(q%2F(q-1)))%2F(2(120%2F(217(zeta(3))))(q%2F(q-1))%20-%201)%20for%20q), yielding the upper bound
$$q < \frac{217\zeta(3)}{217\zeta(3) - 240} \approx 12.5128,$$
from which it follows that $q=5$, since $q$ is a prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  **QED**

Comment: I just hope that WolframAlpha did not commit an erroneous computation.

Comment: In your second to last equation, how are you getting your upper bound for x/(x-1)?

Comment: Hey @JoshuaZ.  To answer your question:  From the line previous to which you refer to, I have a lower bound for $x$ (say $a$, for simplicity).  So I get
$$x > a \implies \frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{a} \implies 1 - \frac{1}{x} > 1 - \frac{1}{a}$$
from which I get
$$\frac{x}{x - 1} < \frac{a}{a - 1}.$$
Please let me know if you have any other further questions.  =)

Comment: After taking to @JoshuaZ, it appears that the denominator of the upper bound for $q$:
$$x - 1 = \frac{240}{217\zeta(3)}\cdot\frac{q}{q - 1} - 1$$
needs to be positive in order for the argument to work.  However, we then have
$$\frac{240}{217\zeta(3)}\cdot\frac{q}{q - 1} - 1 > 0$$
which when solved with [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(240%2F(217(zeta(3))))(q%2F(q-1))+%3E+1) gives
$$1 < q < \frac{217\zeta(3)}{217\zeta(3) - 240}.$$

Comment: So essentially, we are tied up in a circular argument.  It remains to see whether the bounds for $\varphi(N)/N$ could be improved, where $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special/Euler prime $q$.

Comment: So the crux of the remaining "problem" is whether the inequality
$$q < \frac{2\cdot\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)}\cdot\frac{q}{q - 1}}{\bigg(2\cdot\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)}\cdot\frac{q}{q - 1}\bigg) - 1}$$
leads to circular reasoning.  Since $q \geq 5 > 0$, we have
$$0 < q < \frac{2\cdot\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)}\cdot\frac{q}{q - 1}}{\bigg(2\cdot\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)}\cdot\frac{q}{q - 1}\bigg) - 1}.$$
Note that the numerator
$$2\cdot\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)}\cdot\frac{q}{q - 1}$$
is positive under the constraint $q \geq 5$.  Therefore... (cont'd.)

Comment: $$\bigg(2\cdot\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)}\cdot\frac{q}{q - 1}\bigg) - 1 > 0$$
which thereby means that there is no circular reasoning in the argument.

Comment: (Late) update:  As pointed out by @JoshuaZ (as well as one other number theorist), the argument presented in this answer requires 
$$x = \frac{2\varphi(n)}{n}> 1,$$
an inequality which is currently not known.