# Improving $\dfrac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \dfrac{\varphi(m)}{m}$ to $\dfrac{1}{2} < \dfrac{\varphi(m)}{m}$, where $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, totient-function, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Preamble: This question is an offshoot of this [earlier MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3284645).

Consider a hypothetical odd perfect number $N=p^k m^2$ with special/Euler prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.  Let $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$, and let $\varphi(x)$ denote the *Euler's totient function* of $x$.

From the following source:
[Advanced Problem H-661, On Odd Perfect Numbers, Proposed by J. L´opez Gonz´alez, Madrid, Spain and F. Luca, Mexico (Vol. 45, No. 4, November 2007), Fibonacci Quarterly](https://www.fq.math.ca/Problems/Advanced_Problems_NOV2009.pdf), we have the bounds
$$\dfrac{240}{217\zeta(3)} < \dfrac{\sigma(N)\varphi(N)}{N^2} < 1,$$
where we have the rational approximation
$$\dfrac{240}{217\zeta(3)} \approx 0.92008188672520641697672952496390495972393334311564395865.$$

Note that this result significantly improves on the classical (lower) bound(s)
$$\dfrac{6}{{\pi}^2} < \dfrac{\sigma(n)\varphi(n)}{n^2} < 1,$$
which holds for **all** positive integers $n$, where we have the rational approximation
$$\dfrac{6}{{\pi}^2} \approx 0.607927101854026628663276779258365833426152648.$$

As derived in the linked question, we have the bounds
$$\dfrac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \dfrac{\varphi(m)}{m} < \dfrac{5}{8},$$
where we have the rational approximation
$$\dfrac{120}{217\zeta(3)} \approx 0.4600409433626.$$

Here is my initial inquiry:

> **Would it be possible to improve the lower bound for $\varphi(m)/m$ to
> $$\dfrac{1}{2} < \dfrac{\varphi(m)}{m}?$$**

Note that it is **not possible** to have
$$\dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{\varphi(m)}{m}$$
since this implies
$$m=2\varphi(m),$$
which results in the contradiction "LHS is odd, RHS is even".

**MY "ATTEMPT"**

The classical (unconditional) upper bound for
$$\dfrac{\sigma(n)\varphi(n)}{n^2} < 1$$
gives
$$\dfrac{\sigma(n)}{n} < \dfrac{n}{\varphi(n)},$$
which holds for any positive integer $n$.  Letting $n=m$ (the factor of our odd perfect number), we obtain
$$\dfrac{\sigma(m)}{m} < \dfrac{m}{\varphi(m)}.$$
Now, the RHS of the last inequality is bounded from above by $2$ if $1/2 < \varphi(m)/m$.  Hence, we get
$$\dfrac{\sigma(m)}{m} < \dfrac{m}{\varphi(m)} < 2,$$
which does hold (since $m$ is deficient, being a proper factor of the (odd) perfect number $p^k m^2$).

**CAVEAT**

I am, however, aware that it may be possible to have
$$\dfrac{\sigma(m)}{m} < 2 < \dfrac{m}{\varphi(m)},$$
whence the conclusion that I require does not hold.

Here is my final inquiry:

> **It might then be more fruitful to consider the cases
> $$\dfrac{\varphi(m)}{m} < \dfrac{1}{2}$$
> and
> $$\dfrac{1}{2} < \dfrac{\varphi(m)}{m}$$
> separately.  Do you have any suggestions on how this can be done?**