# On the equation $\frac{1}{q}=1-\frac{\varphi(N)/N}{\varphi(n)/n}$, where $N=q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, totient-function, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

**Preamble:** This question is an offshoot of this [earlier MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3284645).

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$, and the *Euler totient function* of $x$ by $\varphi(x)$.

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) given in Eulerian form.  That is, $q$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  (Note that this implies that $q \geq 5$.)

From the following source:
[Advanced Problem H-661, On Odd Perfect Numbers, Proposed by J. L´opez Gonz´alez, Madrid, Spain and F. Luca, Mexico (Vol. 45, No. 4, November 2007), Fibonacci Quarterly](https://www.fq.math.ca/Problems/Advanced_Problems_NOV2009.pdf), we have the bounds
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} < \frac{N}{\sigma(N)} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

However, we also have
$$\frac{\varphi(N)}{N} = \frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k}\cdot\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}.$$
Notice that
$$\frac{4}{5} \leq \frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k} = \frac{q^k \bigg(1 - \frac{1}{q}\bigg)}{q^k} = \frac{q - 1}{q} < 1.$$
Therefore, we have the bounds
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} = \frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k}\cdot\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{\varphi(n)}{n},$$
and
$$\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} \leq \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} = \frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k}\cdot\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{1}{2},$$
which implies that
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{5}{8}.$$

WolframAlpha gives the rational approximation
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} \approx 0.4600409433626.$$

Note that from the equation
$$\frac{\varphi(N)}{N}=\frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k}\cdot\frac{\varphi(n)}{n},$$
we obtain
$$\frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k}=\frac{q-1}{q}=1-\frac{1}{q}=\frac{\varphi(N)/N}{\varphi(n)/n},$$
from which we finally get
$$q = \frac{1}{1 - \Bigg(\frac{\varphi(N)/N}{\varphi(n)/n}\Bigg)}.$$
But since we have obtained
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} < \frac{1}{2},$$
and
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{5}{8},$$
then we get
$$\frac{192}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(N)/N}{\varphi(n)/n} < \frac{217\zeta(3)}{240},$$
which implies that
$$1 - \frac{217\zeta(3)}{240} < 1 - \frac{\varphi(N)/N}{\varphi(n)/n} < 1 - \frac{192}{217\zeta(3)},$$
where we have the rational approximations
$$1 - \frac{217\zeta(3)}{240} \approx -0.086859783273466499715596587699936$$
and
$$1 - \frac{192}{217\zeta(3)} \approx 0.26393449061983486641861638.$$

Note that we are sure that
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} > \frac{\varphi(N)}{N},$$
since otherwise we would get
$$1 - \frac{\varphi(N)/N}{\varphi(n)/n} = \frac{1}{q} \leq 0,$$
which is a contradiction.

Consequently,
$$0 < \frac{1}{q} = 1 - \frac{\varphi(N)/N}{\varphi(n)/n} < 1 - \frac{192}{217\zeta(3)},$$
so that
$$q > \frac{217\zeta(3)}{217\zeta(3) - 192} \approx 3.788818951443435495481230888.$$

Here is my:

> **QUESTION:** Do you see a way on how to improve the lower bound for $q$, given my approach in this post?  If so, how could this be done?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since
$$\frac{1}{q} = 1 - \frac{\varphi(N)/N}{\varphi(n)/n}$$
and $q \geq 5 > 0$, then
$$0 < \frac{1}{q} = 1 - \frac{\varphi(N)/N}{\varphi(n)/n}.$$
It follows that
$$\frac{\varphi(N)/N}{\varphi(n)/n} < 1.$$

**Alas, this is where I get stuck.**

Answer (score 0):

**This is too long for a comment:  I merely wanted to record some thoughts that recently occurred to me, which are related to the problem at hand.**

---

Since
$$\dfrac{1}{q} = \dfrac{\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n}-\dfrac{\varphi(N)}{N}}{\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n}}$$
and $q$ is (the special) prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $q \geq 5$, so that
$$\dfrac{1}{q} \leq \dfrac{1}{5},$$
which implies that
$$\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n}-\dfrac{\varphi(N)}{N} \leq \dfrac{1}{5}\cdot\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \dfrac{1}{5}\cdot\dfrac{5}{8} = \frac{1}{8},$$
since $\varphi(n)/n < 5/8$, from which it follows that
$$\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \dfrac{\varphi(N)}{N} + \dfrac{1}{8} < \dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{8} = \dfrac{5}{8},$$
which *does not* improve on the known upper bound $\varphi(n)/n < 5/8$.

---

We also obtain
$$\dfrac{\varphi(N)}{N} < \dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \dfrac{5}{8},$$
which *does not* improve on the known upper bound $\varphi(N)/N < 1/2$.

Comment: Note that we then obtain $$\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} \leq \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} < \frac{\varphi(n)}{n}.$$